# std::future::wait_for spurious wakeup?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, future

`std::condition_variable::wait_for` takes an optional predicate to internally handle spurious wakeups.  `std::future::wait_for` does not have any such optional arguments.  Is spurious wakeup something I need to guard against if I want to make sure I wait *at least* as long as the specified timeout, or is it already handled in some other way?

Comment: A thread (of a future) has no spurious wake up.

Comment: no, the functions may have the same unqualified name, but conceptually they are quite different

Answer (score 2):

Only condition variables can wake up "spuriously". Apparently, allowing spurious wake-ups simplifies implementation of condition variables on some systems. (The C++ Programming Language 4th ed.)